# Javascript Date() converts 29/Feb/2012 to 1/Mar/2012

Tags: javascript, time

### This is my code:

```
var d = new Date();
var date = 29;
var month = 1; // Feb
var year = 2012; // Bissextile year
d.setUTCDate(date);
d.setUTCMonth(month);
d.setUTCFullYear(year);
d.setUTCHours(0);
d.setUTCMinutes(0);
d.setUTCSeconds(0);
document.write(d.getUTCDate()+"<br />"+d.getUTCMonth()+"<br />"+d);
```

### This is the result in Firefox:

1
2
Thu Mar 01 2012 11:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)

### When the value of date is 28:

28
1
Tue Feb 28 2012 11:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)

### There is no Wednesday!

Is it an error of JS or there is another method to find Wed Feb 29 2012 here?

Comment: it's not a bug, it's a feature

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the order in which you are setting the items.

You're starting from today, which is March 5th, 2014.

You are then setting the date to 29. Result: March 29th, 2014.

Then you set the month to 1. Result: Feburary 29th, 2014. Oh wait, that's wrong because 2014 is not a leap year, so JS corrects it to March 1st, 2014.

Finally, you set the year. Final result is March 1st, 2012.

Try setting the year first, then the day, then the month.

Alternatively, use the constructor properly: `new Date(2012,1,29)` should work just fine.

Comment: I changed the order and the result is correct now, thanks. But if I just use `new Date(2012,1,29)`, The result became:  28
1
Wed Feb 29 2012 00:00:00 GMT+1100 which is weird.  Why does `getUTCDate()` still return 28?

Comment: Ah, because `new Date(2012,1,29)` is creating that date at midnight in your timezone, which is 11 hours ahead of UTC. Therefore UTC is still at 1PM on the previous day. Try `new Date(2012,2,1)` and you'll see February 29th in UTC.